# How I can use Buttons in a cordova application?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, events

hi i want to build a cordova application with two buttons.

I have a plugin for show a toast in my android application.

If I click on the button i dont see a toast, but i execute the code without button i can see the toast.

here is my index.html:

```
<div id="deviceready" class="blink">
    <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
    <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>

    <button onclick="setShortToast()">
        Kurz
    </button>

    <button onclick="setLongToast()">
        Lang
    </button>

</div>
```

Here is my index.js:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },

    setShortToast: function () {
        window.simpleToastPlugin.show("Hallo", 0, function(e){
            //success callback
        }, function(e){
            //error callback
        });
    },

    setLongToast: function() {
        window.simpleToastPlugin.show("Hallo", 1, function(e){
            //success callback
        }, function(e){
            //error callback
        });
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify JS is loaded and try to call  app.setShortToast()